# How to make a switch for an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, switch-statement

Here's my code:

```
var animalArray = ["cow","pig"]

switch animalArray {
case ["cow","pig"],["pig","cow"]:
    println("You Win!")
default:
    println("Keep Trying")
```

I get the error: "Type 'Array' does not conform to protocol 'IntervalType'" for the line "case ["cow","pig"],["pig","cow"]:". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` statement requires an `Int`. Think about this:

```
var animalDict: [String: Int] = ["cow": 0,"pig": 1]
var animalSelection: Int = animalDict["cow"]!

switch animalSelection {
case 0:
    println("The Cow Wins!")
case 1:
    println("The Pig Wins!")
default:
    println("Keep Trying")
}

//prints "The Cow Wins!"
```

#### Edit 1:

Thanks to all for your comments. I think this is more robust code:

```
var animalDict: [String: Int] = ["cow": 0,"pig": 1]
var animalSelection: Int? = animalDict["horse"]

if animalSelection as Int? != nil {
   switch animalSelection! {
   case 0:
       println("The Cow Wins!")
   case 1:
       println("The Pig Wins!")
   default:
       println("Keep Trying")
   }
} else {
    println("Keep Trying")
}

//prints "Keep Trying"
```

It will still print `The Cow Wins` if I say:

```
var animalSelection:Int? = animalDict["cow"]
```

#### Edit 2:

Based on @AirSpeedVelocity's comments I tested the following code. Much more elegant than my own code:

```
var animalDict: [String: Int] = ["cow": 0,"pig": 1]
var animalSelection = animalDict["horse"]

switch animalSelection {
case .Some(0):
    println("The Cow Wins!")
case .Some(1):
    println("The Pig Wins!")
case .None:
    println("Not a valid Selection")
default:
    println("Keep Trying")
}
```

Comment: "The switch statement requires an integer.” No, it doesn’t.  Switches in Swift work with many different types.  It just doesn’t match arrays out of the box.

Comment: Additionally, your code will explode at runtime instead of ever hitting the default, since you will be force-unwrapping a nil value from the dictionary.  Instead you should make `animalSelection` an `Int?`, and do `case .Some(0):`

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity how am I force unwrapping a nil value in this code?  It doesn't explode.  I never post code that hasn't been tested.

Comment: It works for this specific case.  However, the default (“keep trying”) implies you are anticipating a lookup of a value not in the dictionary.  This code can never execute – if the value were not in the dictionary, the return from the dictionary lookup will be nil, and you are force-unwrapping it with `!`.  You should avoid suggesting using `!` like this on stack overflow answers as it is encouraging dangerous habits.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks for the guidance.  I've edited the code to be more robust.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes Thanks for the guidance.  I've edited my code to be more robust.

Comment: @jwlaughton No problem. An alternative to consider: `let animalSelection = animalDict["horse"]; switch animalSelection { case .Some(0): println("The Cow Wins!"); case .Some(1): println("The Pig Wins!"); default: println("Keep Trying") }`.  The `.Some` is the optional enum value for an optional that isn’t nil (`.None` would be a nil value).  `animalSelection` can be declared with `let` since it’s not mutated, and you can use type inference rather than explicit typing (removing clutter).  Note, you don’t need breaks in Swift switches (they do not fall through implicitly).

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Thanks.  Good stuff to know.  I'll run some tests to be sure I understand what you're telling me.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I posted my test of your input.  More elegant to be sure.

Comment: I just found this answer (and downvoted it) because it is definitely starting from the wrong place.  Switches do not need Int.  Agree with @AirspeedVelocity

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with an array. But you could check it with the `contains()` method and iterate over the array you want to test(here `secondArray`):

```
var animalArray:[String] = ["cow", "pig"]
var secondArray:[String] = ["cow", "test"]

for s in secondArray{
    if(contains(animalArray, s)){
        println("animalArray Contains \(s)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to compare two arrays regardless of the order of their entries then I would suggest the following:

```
      var referenceAnimal = ["cow", "pig"]
      var animalsToTest = ["pig", "cow"]


      sort(&referenceAnimal)
      sort(&animalsToTest)


      if referenceAnimal == animalsToTest {
          println("You Win!")
      } else {
          println("Keep Trying")
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If order isn't important, you can do this.

```swift
import Foundation


let animalArray = ["cow","pig"]

extension Array where Element == String  {
  static func ~=(pattern: Array, value: Array) -> Bool {
    return pattern == value
  }
}

switch animalArray {
case ["cow", "pig"], ["pig","cow"]:
    print("You Win!")
default:
    print("Keep Trying")
}
```

Keep in mind, this will apply it to all `Array<String>` you might want to wrap those or go the other way and apply it to all `Equatable`s instead.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, wrapping the switch in a for-in loop is another option.

```
var animalArray = ["cow", "pig"]

for animal in animalArray {
    switch animal {
    case "cow":
        print("win")
    case "pig":
        print("lose")
    default:
        print("try again")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `switch` able to match arrays by overloading the `~=` appropriately:

```
func ~=<T: Equatable>(lhs: [T], rhs: [T]) -> Bool {
    return lhs == rhs
}

var animalArray = ["cow","pig"]

switch animalArray {
case ["cow","pig"],["pig","cow"]:
    println("You Win!”)  // this will now match
default:
    println("Keep Trying")
}
```

It’s questionable whether this is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost identical to @Christian Woerz's answer, but I'm a sucker for `reduce` in these situations.

```
var animalArray = ["cow","pig"]
var answerArray = ["pig","cow"]
let isCorrect = answerArray.reduce(true) { bool, animal in
    return bool && contains(animalArray, animal)
}
```